# If two thread sleep for certain duration (3 sec for example) meantime on a two-core cpu, we will wait for nearly 3 sec till both the sleep done?

Tags: multithreading

As my topic says, if two thread run in my program, and I made them both wait for `3 sec` for example at the same time, on a machine with *two-core* cpu.

I just wait for *nearly* **3 sec** instead of **6 sec**, until the two thread both end sleep, is that right?

The process which distribute two thread to `separate core` is process by the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your two threads will sleep concurrently for roughly 3 seconds. It's unlikely to be exact 3 seconds as a thread execution is not guaranteed by a general OS. It's also not guaranteed as to which CPU core will pick up the thread.

Comment: The distribution of **the two thread to two core** is process by the os?
You needn't to care about the distribution? Just write two thread and the os will do the rest?

Comment: I think yo mean scheduling, not distribution. Scheduling is performed be the OS itself. There is a scheduler available in most OSes that looks into each process and each thread and prioritises which one to run next. A developer has little control as to which thread will be executed next and on which CPU. There are things like thread and process priority and processor affinity, but I think in your case that is not relevant.